# how to get data in MySQL grouped by last 12 months from now

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table in which I want to group count of data in a month from last 12 months

example :

```
count(*) | months
12       | AUG 2022
11       | JULY 2022
0        | JUNE 2022
12       | AUG 2022
.
.
.
etc 
last 12 months
```

and if no data in a particular month then mark It as zero
and i want last 12 months data from current month

data in  in format of:

```
id | data    | datetime 
1  | somedata| 2017-11-23 00:45:54
2  | somedata| 2017-11-23 00:45:54
3  | somedata| 2017-10-23 00:45:54
4  | somedata| 2017-09-23 00:45:54
.
.
.
```

is this possible in MySQL and how?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one. Please replace **DemoTable** with your correct table.

```
   Select DATE_FORMAT(last_12_months.date, '%Y-%m')  AS year_and_month, count(data_table.id) as count
  from (
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 11 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 10 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 9 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 8 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 7 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 6 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 5 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 4 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 3 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 2 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 1 month)  date FROM dual  union
         SELECT  now() month FROM dual
         ) last_12_months Left JOIN
         DemoTable data_table
   on DATE_FORMAT(data_table.dateTime, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(last_12_months.date, '%Y-%m')
   group by DATE_FORMAT(last_12_months.date, '%Y-%m') ;
```

Comment: no this wont work becuase i only want last 12 months data and if the month has no data  it should come as zero

Comment: @Ishaan It works or no ?